# Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

Tags: profile, system-admin

When I try to change field access on System Admin profile I gets the following error

> Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on
>   permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

What should I change in the admin profile so that I can edit this profile without any problems?

I will only add that this field is **not editable** in the profile

[image]

Comment: Facing same issue in Sandbox, seems to look alright in Production.

Comment: Yes, I have this issue on sandbox, but how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't know, I think it's a backend issue and might need to reach out to Salesforce support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems a bug in Salesforce. **Workaround**:

```
1) Go to Manage Users --> User Management Settings  
2) Disable the Enhanced Profile User Interface setting 
3) Go back to the Profile which you want to update 
4) On the profile page, in the Field-Level Security section, click on View to view the existing settings for the object fields 
5) Click on Edit 
6) Update the FLS accordingly
```

Same steps apply for all other settings. Hope this helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue/error where I cannot update any new configs on  the **System Administrator** profile because of the error:

> Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

The issue here is, with the latest Salesforce release(Summer' 18), there was a bug that rolled out, ie., disables the permission: `Subscribe to Dashboards` for the System Administrator profile
But the dependent permission: `Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients` is still enabled. You can find these permissions under: **System Permissions**.

Even a System Administrator user cannot have access to change/modify these **System Permissions**. And without enabling the permission: `Subscribe to Dashboards`, we cannot save any further changes on the System admin profile. Thus creating a ***Dead-lock situation*** as there is a mutual dependency where we cannot make any further updates.

**Solution**: We had to open a case with the Salesforce. The rep mentioned that they already identified this issue as many users have reported already and they can fix it by themselves. So within a day, the issue on our Sandbox has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Salesforce.

> Working with support they escalated my case to tier3. They had the tier3 team run a scrutiny on the Sandbox environment - after this exercise was complete the checkbox reappeared. I had them do this in our UAT enviornment plus some other active Dev Sandboxes. I allowed them to close the case but plan to reopen it if we loose the setting on the profile in production when we're upgraded. We're on the release this coming weekend, so we'll see what happens!

Please find Kristen's solution to resolve the issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DsYVQA0)