# Cannot add record type to standard profile because of unrelated error

Tags: profile, system-admin

I want to assign a case record type to System Administrator. When I try to do this I get the error:

> Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Send to Groups and Roles depends
>   on permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

I can't change these settings because it's a standard profile. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223850/permission-subscribe-to-dashboards-add-recipients-depends-on-permissions-sub)